# Using Watson Knowledge Studio (WKS) Type System Attributes with Discovery

Tags: watson-discovery, watson-knowledge-studio

I have created a WKS model and used type system attributes like role and subtypes,  with the entities during the annotation process. This model will be connected to Watson Discovery. I am not very familiar with discovery at this moment. I want to know how I can extract and use the attributes of Entity types defined in WKS with Watson discovery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure how you can deploy your WKS custom model to Discovery and how to call the mode from Discovery API are described in the following documents:

- [Deploying a machine-learning annotator to IBM Watson Discovery](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/publish-ml.html#publish-ml)
- [Integrating with Watson Knowledge Studio](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/integrate-wks.html)